# Translate wordpress without duplicate custom post

Tags: translation

As I can't find a proper way to do this, I'll just drop this here : 
I run a website where anyone can post offers from fontend.

I want the website to be multi language with switcher and/or browser language detection.

However, I can't produce simply translated post : as users post from frontend, I can't ask them to post 2 times. And I can't make it by myself each time someone post or delete, as it would be too much to handdle.

I tried polylang and so on, that need multiple post, one for each language.

I would need : a way to translate evrything with switcher or browser language detection without multi post OR a way to automaticaly create translated post on the fly.

Any hints ?

Comment: You are looking for WPML (WordPress Mulitilingual). That plugin can copy posts automatically, run them through a translation service and tadaa.. your result.

Comment: Ok. But does this trigger automaticaly, even from frontend ? Same with deletion ? As it's cost money, I'd rather be sure before invest.

Comment: You could also look into using Google Translate, which adds a dropdown menu on the post to select the language. It uses JavaScript to translate, so you don't end up with multiple posts.

Comment: It seems that this bit of code does the trick with polylang. I'll check this this nights.
function turn_blogposts_translation_off( $post_types, $is_settings ) {
  unset( $post_types['alsp_listing'] );
  
  return $post_types;
}

add_filter( 'pll_get_post_types', 'turn_blogposts_translation_off', 10, 2 );